# Persisting tab contents when switching between tabs

Tags: c#, reportviewer

My application has a reports tab where reports are displayed using Reportviewer. If the user switches to a different tab after loading a report in the reportviewer, the contents get reset while navigating back to Reports tab. Is there a way to retain the current report?

Comment: Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that there is code refreshing the ReportViewer control on the tab change? This will cause the report to refresh during the tab switch.